# Deny request to all json files from particular path in Nginx

Tags: json, nginx, block

Deny request to all json files from particular path in Nginx.

We have to block all json files,which is served from /home/assests/js/.

```
location /home/assets/js/mxgraph/package1.json {
    deny all;
}

location /home/assets/js/mxgraph/package2.json {
    deny all;
}

location /home/assets/js/mxgraph/package3.json {
    deny all;
}

location /home/assets/js/mxgraph/package4.json {
    deny all;
}
```

We are able to block all above json files,but how we can combine these blocks into one,saying block all *.json files need to deny from those path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match all URIs ending with `.json` you would need to use a regular expression.

For example:

```
location ~ ^/home/assets/js/.*\.json$ { deny all; }
```

Regular expression `location` statements are evaluated in order until a matching rule is found, so this statement should be placed above any conflicting regular expressions. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.